# Is there a way to combine a query in SQL using if elif else scenario?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to calculate the `total_uniterrupted` time of an activity instance such that there are 2 scenarios:

1. When activity 1 is active, then activity 2 interrupts activity 1, then activity 2 ends before activity 1.

   [scenario 1 graphical representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNyTT.png)

   where `i` is the current instance and `ac` represents other instance in the instance table

Query for scenario 1 is:

```
total uninterrupted time = (i.end – i.start) – (ac.end – ac.start)
where ac.start between i.start and i.end and ac.end <= i.end
```

2. When activity 1 is active, then activity 2 interrupts activity 1, then activity 1 ends before activity 2

   [scenario 2 graphical represenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1oU.png)

Query for scenario 2 is:

```
Total uninterrupted time = (i.end – i.start) – (i.end – ac.start) 
where ac.start between i.start and i.end and ac.end >= i.end
```

I have achieved to calculate the total_uninterrupted time for both scenarios separately but I need them to be in the same query using like an if else kind of command.

I don't know if something like this is possible in SQL:

```
IF (ac.start BETWEEN i.start AND i.end AND ac.end <= i.end)  
   THEN (i.end – i.start) – (ac.end – ac.start) AS total_uninterrupted_time

ELSE IF (ac.start BETWEEN i.start AND i.end AND ac.end <= i.end) 
    THEN (i.end – i.start) – (i.end – ac.start) AS total_uninterrupted_time
```

I tried this for scenario 1:

```
SELECT 
    i.instanceid, i.activityid, i.start, i.end,
    i.end - i.start as totalWithInterruptions,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instance AS ac 
         WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid 
           AND ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end)) AS interrupted,
    COALESCE((SELECT (ac.end - ac.start) 
              FROM instance AS ac 
              WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid 
                AND ac.start BETWEEN i.start AND i.end 
                AND ac.end <= i.end), 0) AS interruptions,
    SUM((COALESCE((i.end - i.start), 0) - COALESCE((SELECT (ac.end - ac.start) FROM instance AS ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid AND ac.start BETWEEN i.start AND i.end AND ac.end <= i.end), 0))) AS timeWithoutInterruptions
FROM 
    instance AS i 
WHERE 
    userid = 2 
GROUP BY 
    i.instanceid
```

and the result I got was

[scenario 1 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzPGs.png)

This only executed the row 2 and 3 correctly because the end time of row  3 was less than the end time of row 2 (ac.end <= i.end)

But the scenario 2 works for the row 1 instead, which is:

```
SELECT i.instanceid, i.activityid, i.start, i.end,
        i.end - i.start as totalWithInterruptions,
        SUM((SELECT count(*) from instance as ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid and ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end )) as interrupted,
        COALESCE((SELECT (i.end - ac.start) FROM instance as ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid and ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end and ac.end >= i.end),0) as interruptions,
        SUM((COALESCE((i.end - i.start),0) - COALESCE((SELECT (i.end - ac.start) FROM instance as ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid and ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end and ac.end >= i.end),0))) as timeWithoutInterruptions
        FROM instance as i WHERE userid = 2 GROUP BY i.instanceid
```

and the result i got was [scenerio 2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25HJ7.png)
This only worked for row 1.

I tried combining the query that performs the timeWithoutInterruptions together for both scenerio 1 and 2 so that for every row when given the right condition the correct calculation is executed by doing:

```
SUM((COALESCE((i.end - i.start),0) – ( 
COALESCE((SELECT (ac.end - ac.start) FROM instance as ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid and ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end and ac.end <= i.end),0) 
OR 
COALESCE((SELECT (ac.end - ac.start) FROM instance as ac WHERE ac.instanceid != i.instanceid and ac.start BETWEEN i.start and i.end and ac.end >= i.end),0)
))) as time
```

but this gave me an error. Is there any other way I can combine the 2 scenarios into 1 to do the calculation for the interruptions and timeWithoutInterruptions.

The correct result that is supposed to be displayed in the interruptions column is [21, 22, 0] and in the timeWithoutInterruptions column is [4, 6, 22]

Thanks.

Comment: You can do separate queries for each scenario, and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two separate DBMSs, with entirely different functionality and syntax. Please remove the tag for the one that you are not using. Tags have relevance and meaning, and should not be misused. Tag spamming is a good way to get your question downvoted or closed. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: @Barmar. I tried the union but it gave me gave me two rows for the same instance using both queries. That did not solve the combination of the two queries

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer. Just some questions for clarification.

- An **Interruption**, according to description, is the number of activities occurred after an activity started but before it ended.
- **Time w/o Interruption** is the duration no other activities were in flight.
- **Time w/ Interruption** is the duration that other activity(ies) was/were in flight.

If the above description is correct. This could be more complicated than combining two queries. Please refer to the diagram below for four different scenarios and some of them are not handled by the two queries.

[image]

Comment: The description for the interruption, time w/o interruption and time w/ interruption is correct. And there are multiple scenarios for calculating the interruptions and the time w/o interruption. I am trying to figure out how I can combine the queries for all the scenarios into one. Or If there is a better way of handling or solving the problem.

Comment: @AdeyinkaMariamAbiola The scenario is similar to `gaps and islands problem`, which you can find lots of information on internet. The effort may not be trivial.